# javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException: Failed to commit transaction Transaction

Tags: java, transactions, neo4j, cypher, heuristics

I am trying to delete a node.

i know for deleting node first i have to delete relationship.

```
MATCH (n:`Dummy`)
WHERE n.uuid='1aa41234-aaaa-xxxx-ffff-xxxx11xx0x62'
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
delete n,r
```

but its not working

> javax.transaction.HeuristicRollbackException: Failed to commit
>   transaction Transaction(80074,
>   owner:"qtp10775679-13464")[STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION,Resources=1],
>   transaction rolled back ---> Transaction handler failed.

Comment: Would user who downvoted please indicate what is wrong with the question? I don't see it.

Comment: Are you using any custom TransactionEventHandlers or extensions?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster yes i am using TransactionEventHandlers

Comment: Do you have an index on `:Dummy(uuid)` can you share your query plan?

Comment: @MichaelHunger i don't know about that  indexing is applied or not,
can you tell me how i can check for indexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that a [transaction event handler's beforeCommit](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html#beforeCommit(org.neo4j.graphdb.event.TransactionData)) method threw an exception. If that happens the transaction will be rolled back.

Maybe `data/graph.db/messages.log` contains a stacktrace. If not I suggest to wrap the contents of your `beforeCommit()` into a try catch block that catches any exception, prints their stacktrace and rethrows it.